# Slow response from SELECT query

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have 50 lac rows (i.e. 5 million rows) in `student` table.

I fire `select * from student where s_name like('%something word%') limit 0,5`.

I define indexing on `s_name` column.

That query takes 2 minutes or more sometimes.

I want quick response within 5 seconds or faster for that type of query.

How...?

I tried the below query also:

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from student  ORDER BY s_name LIMIT 0,10) as s 
WHERE `status` = 'active' AND ( `s_name ` LIKE ('%a%') or `f_name ` LIKE ('%a%')) 
ORDER BY s_name LIMIT 0,5
```

Code taken and adjusted from: [search for something in the first 1000 records in the table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40221/search-for-something-in-the-first-1000-records-in-the-table)

Comment: You need to clarify your question. What is "lac"? Let us know what rdbms and version you are using. And what are you trying to accomplish with this type of query in the first place?

Comment: @DanielHutmacher: [Lac or Lakh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh), a measurement unit used in India.

Comment: Using LIKE('%something word%') with a prefix wildcard %requires a scan of a table or index, since it cannot seek directly to the qualifying strings. Would full text indexing serve you better?

Answer (score 1):

First of All indexes wont be used if used **%keyword%** , it should be **keyword%**.

after you do that add index on

index (status, s_name, f_name)